# Alternative for g:select (multiple values)

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, selection

I have a Domain Class `Project` with a one-to-many property `users` :

```
static hasMany = [users: User]
```

In my scaffolding code the view is created with:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: projectInstance, field: 'users', 'error')} ">
    <label for="users">
        <g:message code="project.users.label" default="Users" />        
    </label>
    <g:select name="users" from="${usermanagement.User.list()}" multiple="multiple" optionKey="id" size="5" value="${projectInstance?.users*.id}" class="many-to-many"/>
</div>
```

This results in a simple list where I can select multiple users. The user list is expected to be quite big so this selection isn't really viable. Is there a simple way in grails to do this a bit more comfortable? The best solution I can imagine would be a list with an autocomplete searchform and a second list where the selected entries are displayed.

I don't think that there is an easy way to do this and that I probably have to use javascript or jquery (autocomplete etc.)

Any help improving my current status (selection from huge list via `ctrl + click`)
would be very appreciated.

Comment: Manually you could do something like this https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/38c6297cce03d6ccfea3b280723c135a15a7a2a1/grails-app/views/autoComplete/_AutoCompleteBasic.gsp  - where you autocomplete and onChange - then add the value to an existing list to a checked list of selected values like i done here: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/jssh/blob/master/grails-app/views/jsshadmin/_autoServer.gsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is using some javascript based stuff like [boostrap select2](https://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/3.5.2.html) or [Kendo UI Multiselect](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index). They are based on a html `select` box that unobtrusively enhanced the selection model of a this html element. So there is no real javascript code to implement, since the selection model for the html form stays the same as with disabled javascript.

Comment: I personally prefer select2 over kendo. Kendo components are a bit awkward to test with selenium/geb.

Comment: this is the same situation that i experienced as well. What you could do, is to use the kendo ui javascript API to trigger certain actions from geb - but this is not the normal way geb is supposed to be executed...

Answer (score 3):

There is a jQuery plugin called Chosen that will do what you are wanting, it supports multiple selections. I have a use case much like yours in one of my apps and Chosen worked out great:

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Thanks! Do you use it with grails too? Do I need to add jQuery UI aswell or can I just add chosen js to my resources? How do I use this with my `<g:select />` with this plugin?

Comment: Yes, I use the jquery plugin with Grails just fine. Once you are at the view you are dealing with normal HTML stuff so any javascript code will work just fine. g:select ends up just generating a standard select, just give it an id and use a jquery selector to get a reference to your selector and then call  .chosen() on it like normal. Don't let the magic of the taglibs confuse you, when it is all said and done normal HTML is produced and you can use javascript accordingly.

Comment: You don't need jquery UI.

Comment: Also note that the options Mario David gave you in his answer will work great too.

Comment: Where do I have to put .chosen() ? I gave ´g:select´ an id but don't know really where and how to call the chosen plugin.

Comment: It works pretty good for now. The only problem I have is that I cant select nothing. Is there an option for this plugin to allow it?

Comment: Maybe open a new question with an example of what you have and someone can probably tell you why it isn't working.